# isModified and pre-save mongoose...Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Hi i want save with hashed password only if password is change, so i used isModified function in pre-save, but its always return false even i changed the password. The reason that i am trying to do this is because i dont want to change and save my password when i change other properties.

```
router.post('/changepw', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$set: req.body},{ new: true }, function (err, user){

        if (err) {
          return err;
        } 
        else {

          if (req.body.password) {
            user.password = req.body.password;
            user.save();
          } else { 

          }

        }
        res.redirect('/profile');
    });
});
```

like here i dont want to change my password when i change my graduated value.

```
router.post('/edit', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: req.user._id
    }, {
        $set: {
            name: req.body.name,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            classc: req.body.classc,
            major: req.body.major,
            minor: req.body.minor,
            linkedin: req.body.linkedin,
            bio: req.body.bio
        }
    }, {
        new: true
    }, function (err, user, done) {

        if (err) {
            return err;
        } else {

            if (typeof req.body.graduated == 'undefined') {
                user.graduated = false;


            } else if (typeof req.body.graduated == 'string') {

                user.graduated = true;

            }

            user.save();
        }
        res.redirect('/profile');
    });
});
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
console.log(this.isModified('password'));                                                                                                                                        
    if(this.password && this.isModified('password')){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        this.password  = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8),null);                                                                                                             
    }

    next()                                                                                                                                                                     
});
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

note that when you're using `findAndUpdate()` method, the pre-save hook is not triggered. Check the Mongoose documentation by using new hooks: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  // Only run this function if password was moddified (not on other update functions)
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();
  // Hash password with strength of 12
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
  //remove the confirm field 
  this.passwordConfirm = undefined;
});
```

Comment: This is not going to be called during `User.findOneAndUpdate`.

Comment: As per the docs, it does
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

Comment: Definitely not. Further down the page you linked to there is a chapter "Notes on findAndUpdate() and Query Middleware". It says "Pre and post `save()` hooks are not executed on `update()`, `findOneAndUpdate()`, etc." Also, "You cannot access the document being updated in `pre('updateOne')` or `pre('findOneAndUpdate')` query middleware." The OP modifies `user` twice. Maybe a combination of `findById()` and `user.save()`would be better. I will add an answer with a suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

`findOneAndUpdate()`already updates `user`, so in the callback function you provided `user` is already up to date. When you call `user.save()` in that callback, the pre `save()` hook will be called, but `isModified('password')` will be false.

If you provide a new password with `req.body`, the password will land in the database unhashed, since "Pre and post `save()` hooks are not executed on `update()`, `findOneAndUpdate()`, etc." ([see documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes)). If you then compare the password in `req.body` and `user`, they will be the same and you cannot decide whether to trigger the hash function with a `save()` or not.

Leave your pre `save()` hook as is and do the update as a combination of `findById()` and `save()`:

```
  User.findById(req.user._id, (err, user) => {
    if (err)
      handleYourErrorAndLeave(err)
  
    // Update all user attributes which are different or missing from user with values from req.body
    Object.assign(user, req.body)

    // Save the updated user object.
    // pre save() hook will be triggered and isModified('password') should be correct
    user.save()
      .then(savedUser => {
        res.redirect('/profile')
      }) 
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to manupulate password from model. This is the one place where you will be able to do update or skeep update a password along with other values based on your needs.

```
// Encrypt password before saving into database
userSchema.pre("save", async 
 function(next) {
 if (!this.isModified("password")) {
  return next();
 }
 const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
 const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
 this.password = hashedPassword;
 next();
});
```