# bcryptjs is not working inside a mongoose schema method

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema, bcryptjs

bcryptjs version: `"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3"`

mongoose version: `"mongoose": "^6.0.12"`

I am trying to encrypt user password on user creation or password update. Data is inserted successfully but the password is not encrypted. This is my schema (I copied it from my previous project which was working correctly):

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    votedFor: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Election'
      }
    ],
    finishedVoting: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  // Only run this function if password was actually modified
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  // Hash the password with salt 10
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);

  next();
});
```

In the database, I see the password as a plain text(unencrypted). So I tried using callback function instead of `async/await` as suggested in other answers:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    console.log("encryption")

    // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    console.log("started encrypting")

    // generate a salt
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        // hash the password using our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

Did not help. I deleted the collection and re-inserted the data. Again the password remains unenrypted. I did not see `console.log("encryption")` nor `console.log("started encrypting")` while inserting. This is some users data that I am inserting:

```
const voters = [
  {
    username: "194199",
    password: "FA654644", //will be encrypted
    isAdmin: false,
    finishedVoting: false
    // votedFor: [Object], //
  },
  {
    username: "184183",
    password: "MB454644", //will be encrypted
    isAdmin: false,
    finishedVoting: false
    // votedFor: [Object], //
  },
  {
    username: "194324",
    password: "FA651684", //will be encrypted
    isAdmin: false,
    finishedVoting: false
    // votedFor: [Object], //
  }
]
```

Comment: Could it be possible that you add your users before actually adding the .pre("save") middleware?

Comment: @GoldenretriverYT Could be. Let's say, first I created the schema without the `pre('save')` method and registered this wrong schema with ` mongoose.model('User', userSchema)`. Is it possible that mongoose is using that wrong version instead of the updated version(the save method added)? If yes how can I register my updated schema?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581825/ismodified-and-pre-save-mongoose-nodejs